# Decision in Activity Diagram with multiple Object Flows

Tags: uml

I tried to reduce my problem to the following simple example. If the profit is low and the customer is not a regular one then the order should become canceled. In all other cases (low/regular, high/*) the order is to be executed. **How should I model the disconnected part in the middle?**
[image: Example Activity Diagram]
Wheter or not the client corresponding to order is a regular client follows from the data model:

[image: Details in data model]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are looking for the formally correct way to model this. Here it is:
[image]

If less formality is sufficient, you could skip the decision input flows and simply assume that the guards have access to any objects in the scope of the activity. Then one decision node is sufficient with a guard `[profit=low AND not order.customer.regular Customer]`.

Comment: I would even say using just one decision node and one AND guard would be preferred. The question doesn't say anything about the order of decision making and such depiction would be presenting exactly that. You may think of adding a respective diagram as well to even further improve your answer.

Comment: @Ister Just one decision node cannot have two incoming «decisionInputFlows». Therefore, it is no option if we use such flows.  Also, estimating the profit would be unnecessary, if it is a regular customer, so we probably _should_ first check the customer, even when we don't use «decisionInputFlows».